# How to express something like classmate, colleague for some scientific fields?

Tags: meaning

Assume there are only 3 people A, B, C working for a company. In other words, the employees of the company consists of A, B and C. So, A is a colleague of B or C.

Machine learning (M) is a field of computer science, consists of supervised learning (S), unsupervised learning (U) and reinforcement learning (R).

Similar to "colleague", is there a term used to describe the relationship between several different and related sub-fields (M, S, U) within a field (R)?

M, S, U and R are not commonly used abbreviation, I used them here just to make the expression easier to understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case, I would use a particular sense of [**counterpart**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/counterpart):

> **2 b** : something that completes : COMPLEMENT
>   // the lead actress and her male *counterpart*

When you divide something into parts, each part (*counterpart*) is an essential component of the whole.

So:

> Supervised learning (S), unsupervised learning (U), and reinforcement learning (R) are *counterparts* of each other (within the field of computer science).